# Excel VBA this should be working but it's not

Tags: vba, excel, search

What I want to do, is when I save my excel file, I want the script to check for all the cells that has the "$" as last character and check if there is a cell with the name "Backup" in the same column as it found a cell with , and if there is, only then apply my script

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim c As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim isbackup As Boolean
isbackup = False

For Each c In Range("A1:N60")
If Right(c, 1) = "$" Then y = c.Column: x = c.Row
    For i = 1 To 60
        If Cells(i, y).Value = "Backup" Then
            isbackup = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
If isbackup = True And Right(c, 1) = "$" Then <my script>
Next c
```

I don't see any syntax or logical errors, but I get the error code

> 1004: "application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: If your first `If` is false for the first `c` then y = 0.  ==> `Cells(1,0)` does not exist hence the Error 1004.  Also you should be more explicit in the definition of the `Range` ex.: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:N60")`

Comment: Use F8 to single-cycle. Hover over a variable to see its value. Use `debug.print ..` to see what's going on. There are other debugging options.

Comment: this is not working because after your first `if` , you should start a new line and stop the then block with `end if`. also i'd use `Right(c.address, 1) = "$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim isbackup As Boolean
    isbackup = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:N60")

    For Each c In rng

        If Right(c, 1) = "$" Then
            y = c.Column: x = c.Row

            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count '--> I find this more flexible
                If Cells(i, y).Value = "Backup" Then
                    isbackup = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

        End If

        If isbackup = True And Right(c, 1) = "$" Then DoEvents 'Replaced by your script

    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: this is perfect! I love you! :-) The reason I did not use "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)" is because I use multiple sheets, but I will put the whole thing in a loop to apply for all of the worksheets.

Comment: but there is still a problem with it... It also works for columns that has no "Backup" cells in them. I'll try to fix it

Comment: I think it is because it cycles trough c for every cell and once the isbackup becomes true, it will remain true, so we need to find a way to make it false again after geting to a row where there is no "Backup"

Comment: ok I got it working, just had to place the "If isbackup = True And Right(c, 1) = "$" Then DoEvents 'Replaced by your script" after the isbackup = True, and it is working as a dream! Thank you again for your help! This is great!